# Android - Loading Bitmaps with AsyncTask inside RecyclerView-Adapter (ViewPager)

Tags: bitmap, android-asynctask, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I'm asking for your help, once again. I'm writing an app which uses a ViewPager with nested RecyclerView. I'm loading some pictures, so the UI is pretty slow, while waiting for them to load. Especially, when the Internet connection is not good. I tought to use the AsyncTask, but can't get it to communicate with the "onBindViewHolder"-method to place the Bitmap.

You'll find the code [for example here](https://github.com/Artishock88/Trendevent/blob/master/app/src/main/java/de/artmedia/artyom/trendevent_screentest/MyBlockAdapter.java). How can I let the ressources load in Background in this case? I'd greatly appreciate any help or advice.

[EDIT] Could I load the entire ViewHolder or execute the onBindViewHolder in Background?

Answer (score 1):

I use Picasso for loading images (http://square.github.io/picasso/), and it seems to work very well. You should be able to replace your AsyncTasks with it if I'm understanding your question correctly. It also provides the ability to display a placeholder image in case of slow connections.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll try out the library.

Comment: Picasso works really well in this case, thanks for the hint. How is it, when the developer decides to remove the library? And how do I appropriatley credit the dev behind Picasso?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by your first question. As for the second, Picasso is licensed under the Apache license. If you check out the documentation for that, it will let you know how it applies to your app and how to appropriately credit.